# Retrieving updated state of members from other screen

Tags: flutter

I have a 2-screen flutter app. With the value of some variables updated from api response.

In my 1st screen, I updated using setState (only including the part of code for updating values)

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  print(response.data['user_count']);
  setState(() {
    machineCount = response.data['machine_count'];
    userCount = response.data['user_count'];
  });
  print(userCount);
  // return SessionResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to update table.');
}
```

The printed values are correct verifying from my terminal.

In 2nd screen I declare a variable to read from the 1st screen variable's state, and trying to display on the screen

```
class ResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {


const ResultScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var result = MyHomePageState.userCount; <<< trying to get from the 1st screen
    var id = MyHomePageState.id;
    var machineCount = MyHomePageState.machineCount;
```

and under the widget, i displayed with:

```
Text(
     '$result',
     style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
   ),
```

But the value displayed is the initialized value `0`. not same as printed value which I verified it has updated the state.

If I don't use the variable from the response, but instead use another variable which I `setState` with counter++, It will display on the 2nd screen correctly with the updated values.

What has gone wrong and why is it not updating from the http response's `setState` but able to retrieve if i update counter++ locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call a variable from another view like that. In `var result = MyHomePageState.userCount;` is not the instance of your view displayed in Screen 1. If you want to pass a variable from a view to another try something like this:

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String variable;
  Screen2({Key key, @required this.variable}) : super(key: key);
```

And when you call your second screen like with a navigator set the variable on this way:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Screen2(variable: 'whatever',),
    ));
```

Comment: thanks @Miguel I tried but still getting 0. 

on my trigger i changed to: 
```await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ResultScreen(userCount: userCount)),
                        );```

and in 2nd screen `ResultScreen({Key? key, @required this.userCount})` but still getting 0.

Why when i use the other variable, i can retrieve the value with updated state though? (eg. counter final value that is updated with counter++)

Comment: actually i realised, it's getting updated, but when i navigate to the second screen, it will always show the earlier session number. i.e. lagging 1 session behind, showing the result of the past value wrapped up.

Comment: i supposed that you call await navigator... after request end, right? It is the only case i imagine for this issue

Comment: I figured out the issue, thanks Miguel! It is indeed mistake on my end, thanks for the suggestion!